# How do I create two tasks in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Java project with Gradle as build system.
I need to create two one-purpose **build tasks**, but with different versions of **jar** file.
Specifically, i need:

- for build task in **local machine** use *-LOCAL* version for .jar (for example **projectName-LOCAL.jar**)
- for build task in **GitLab CI\CD** system use numbered version (**projectName-1.1.1.jar**)

The version for GitLab CI\CD taken from commit tag, from GitLab predefined ENV variables.

So, i have a default **build.gradle** file, where:

```
group = 'projectName'
version = 'LOCAL'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "projectName.Application"
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

This task must run on local machine and create **projectName-LOCAL.jar**. What he's doing is.
How can I implement this in another task with **numbered** version especially for GitLab CI\CD?

Comment: Hi, Welcome.  This question is very open ended, there are quite a few different approaches to achieve what you're asking.  Unfortunately, members here usually aren't interested in doing your work for you.  You will have more luck in general if you provide examples of your efforts with details on what you tried and why they didn't work.  I recommend looking into making your own ad-hoc tasks.  Then separately look into how you can extend tasks to inherit behavior (such as from the Jar task type).

Comment: There are plugins as well, such as the shadow jar plugin, which takes a lot of work out of jar tasks like this in some ways.  However, using it effectively will require you understand the basics of creating and configuring tasks as well.  I used shadow as an example, this plugin specifically is for creating fat jars that contain all dependencies to run standalone which may or may not suit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle by default names jar files as `${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${classifier}.${extension}`.

So you can simply change `version` depending on a condition.

Something like this should work:

```
ext {
    isLocal = System.getenv('ENV') == 'LOCAL'
}

jar {
    if (isLocal) version = 'LOCAL'
}
```

For working with local, you can use `ENV=LOCAL ./gradlew jar` and use your normal commands without the ENV part for GitLab.